# how deleted the missing data in large data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data.frame, if the `code1` and `code2` and `code3` are missing then I will deleted

```
DATE        BIRTHDAY     ID   code1  code2  code3   ID_SEX
19970406    19501022     1      32     4      2        F
19980508    19501022     1                             F
19980508    19501022     1       2     56     43       F
19990805    19500502     2       23    56              M
20000321    19500502     2       4                     M
20060715    19500322     3                             F
```

I want this

```
DATE        BIRTHDAY     ID   code1  code2  code3   ID_SEX
19970406    19501022     1      32     4      2        F
19980508    19501022     1       2     56     43       F
19990805    19500502     2       23    56              M
20000321    19500502     2       4                     M
```

the id may by rep.

Comment: The way you wrote your data, you have shown blanks in what should be numeric or integer columns.  This cannot happen since there is no "blank" with numbers.  check `str(yourdata)` to confirm your columns are in fact numbers then you can use the `is.na` answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you call your data.frame `mydata`:

```
mydata[ 
  apply( mydata[ c("code1", "code2", "code3") ], 1, function(x){
    ! all( is.na( x ) )
  }),
]
```

**Edit:**

Considering Justins comment and just in case your code columns are not numeric but of type `character` or `factor` and the missing values are actually not `NA`s but empty strings (`""`) you could capture the desired rows with

```
mydata[ 
  apply( mydata[ c("code1", "code2", "code3") ], 1, function(x){
    any( x != "" )
  }),
]
```

Comment: @Hannah sorry, there was a closing bracket missing. I fixed it. So missing value means in your case the actual value is `""`?

Comment: yes missing in data is"",but the code not only have number . for example v103 A424

Comment: Ok, but then the second solution should work, right? Let me know if I misunderstood something or make your question clearer please.

Comment: no,but they put wrong: Unexpected ']' in：
"                    },
               ]"

Comment: @Hannah, see my my comment four above this one: I fixed the code already, since there was a bracket missing.

Comment: @Hannah and as a frequent reminder: Let us know if this entirely answers your question. If this is already the case, it'd be nice if you accept it by clicking the check mark.